# Get keys from one table and values from another mysql

Tags: mysql

I've been looking for an answer all day, and I simple can't crack it. I have three tables:

```
Keys
-------------------
| ID  | name      |
-------------------
| 1   | title     |
-------------------
| 2   | text      |
-------------------
```

The first table contains a list of keys that comprise a page.

```
Values
---------------------------------
| ID  | value      | key | page |
---------------------------------
| 1   | 'My title' | 1   | 1    |
---------------------------------
| 2   | 'Content'  | 2   | 1    |
---------------------------------
| 1   | 'MyTitle2' | 1   | 2    |
---------------------------------
```

The second is a list of values for the keys, related to the page they are on

```
Pages
--------------------
| ID  | name       |
--------------------
| 1   | 'A page'   |
--------------------
| 2   | 'Another'  |
--------------------
```

The third is a list of pages to tie them all together.

When I request a page, I want to get back all the keys, regardless of the values that exist in the tables above. But I do want to get back the values for columns where they exist.

I have tried a couple of things, but none of them seem to return me a guaranteed full list of keys with potential values filled in.

The first thing I tried was to return all keys that are either correct or NOT NULL, as such:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM Keys k
LEFT JOIN Values v
ON k.id = v.key
WHERE (v.page = 1
OR v.page IS NULL)
```

Here I want to

```
1. Get all keys
2. Left Join them with values
3. Filter out the keys that don't belong to this page
```

However, once there is data in the Values array the left join will join regardless of the page id, and then filter out the non-matches, leaving me with *no matches*. I want it to return empty keys to me.

I've also tried the `IN` keyword but I don't seem to have any success with that either (possible because it seems rather confusing to me at this point).

So my question is **Can I return a list of keys with values (if they exist in another table and match certain criteria)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you stack overflow, as typing in the question resulted in me reformulating and coming up with the result (it had me stumped for days):

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM Keys k
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM Values v2 WHERE v2.page = 1) as v
ON k.id = v.key
```

Apparently you can LEFT JOIN any (for lack of better word and more knowledge to describe it) 'array' of results as if it itself is a table, so you can select the values conditionally. If they don't exist, the left join returns empty results, but the keys are still returned as is.